# May a while loop be used with yield in scala

Tags: scala, yield

Here is the standard format for a for/yield in scala: notice it expects a collection - whose elements drive the iteration.

```
for (blah <- blahs) yield someThingDependentOnBlah
```

I have a situation where an indeterminate number of iterations will occur in a loop. The inner loop logic determines how many will be executed.

```
while (condition) { some logic that affects the triggering condition } yield blah
```

Each iteration will generate one element of a sequence - just like a yield is programmed to do.  What is a recommended way to do this?

Comment: This is kind of vague. `for ... yield` maps an immutable structure to another immutable structure, but `while` is generally used for manipulating some mutable state, so there isn't an obvious `yield` analog. Could you provide more details about what you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can

```
Iterator.continually{ some logic; blah }.takeWhile(condition)
```

to get pretty much the same thing.  You'll need to use something mutable (e.g. a var) for the logic to impact the condition.  Otherwise you can

```
Iterator.iterate((blah, whatever)){ case (_,w) => (blah, some logic on w) }.
         takeWhile(condition on _._2).
         map(_._1)
```

Comment: Thanks This covers the spirit of what I was looking for

Comment: @RexKerr How about a do while?

Comment: @Sohaib - Iterators make that awkward with their current set of methods.  You can always cache an element, though.

Answer (score 2):

Using for comprehensions is the wrong thing for that. What you describe is generally done by `unfold`, though that method is not present in Scala's standard library. You can find it in Scalaz, though.

Comment: OK. i just did a normal while loop and inside of it appended to an ArrayBuffer

Comment: Scala standard collections have huge functionality holes in them.. but switching to scalaz is a little radical for the rest of us...

Comment: @matanster That's like saying using Apache Commons is a little radical. Using _all_ Apache Commons might be radical, but, say, just commons-lang is fine. It just so happens that Scalaz comes with everything in it, but you *can* use it just for, to use the example, `unfold`.

Comment: Oh well, you have a point there. Alas the learning curve.. but is the performance of scalaz at par?

Comment: Then I might try it, but this means an even longer learning curve for anyone who reads my Scala code... hope you are right :)

Comment: I typically work in teams that have newbies to scala (data science teams with python/R or ETL teams with java/SQL).  `scalaz` enhances scala to the point of being essentially a different dialect:  so adding that to the mix  is unlikely to "fly".

Answer (score 1):

Another way similar to suggestion by @rexkerr:

```
 blahs.toIterator.map{ do something }.takeWhile(condition)
```

This feels a bit more natural than the `Iterator.continually`

Comment: can you explain with example?