# Scala: read in ResultSet with something like while yield?

Tags: scala, while-loop, yield

I'm using Scala, and have a [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) with an unknown number of elements. I'd like to loop through the set, processing each row, and end up with an array of the processed elements. The function `rs.next()` moves the pointer to the next element and returns `true` if that element is a meaningful row and `false` if that element is not (either after the last row, or the return was empty to begin with). So even though the following [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090229/why-yield-can-not-work-with-while-loop-in-scala), I'd like something structured like:

```
while (rs.next()) yield new foo(rs)
```

I tried the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558120/may-a-while-loop-be-used-with-yield-in-scala), like so:

```
if (rs.next()) Iterator.continually(new foo(rs)).takeWhile(rs.next())
```

But this doesn't work because the element is created *before* the condition is checked, behaving as a do-while which has to process the first bad element. As written, it will create a `foo` using the last element of the resultset *but not return it* and requires the initial `rs.next()` to get started.

I have multiple other ways to approach this problem: another query to count the number of elements and then using `take`, using a boolean var that's set equal to `rs.next()` and then used to return a null element if false and also used for the `takeWhile`, a mutable collection that is added to in a while loop, and so on.

But I feel like I must be missing something, because some part of each of those solutions feels inelegant. Is there a simple functional construction that will repeatedly check a condition, creating an element to add to an iterator so long as the condition is true?

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636545/treating-an-sql-resultset-like-a-scala-stream ?

Comment: @PeterNeyens Yes, thanks! That does what I would like and looks very reusable.